# nothing happened when i click download button in gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i try to download file on my database in gridview, but nothing happened when i click download link..

this my aspx.code

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="table table-striped responsive" ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="NoSurat" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" PageSize="5">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No Surat">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblIDs" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NoSurat")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NoSurat")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Perihal" HeaderText="Perihal" SortExpression="Perihal" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="AsalSurat" HeaderText="Asal Surat" SortExpression="AsalSurat" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="IsiSurat" HeaderText="Isi Surat" SortExpression="IsiSurat" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="tglsurat_terima" HeaderText="Tanggal Diterima" SortExpression="tglsurat_terima" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="tglsurat_kirim" HeaderText="Tanggal Dikirim" SortExpression="tglsurat_kirim" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="keterangan" HeaderText="Ket Surat" SortExpression="keterangan" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="namesScan" HeaderText="Nama File" SortExpression="namesScan" />                     
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="tglupload" HeaderText="Tanggal Upload Surat" SortExpression="tglupload" />

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions" ShowHeader="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" CssClass="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" OnClientClick="return confirm('Anda yakin untuk menghapus?'); "></asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="lnkDownload_Click"></asp:LinkButton>  
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

And my code behind

```
protected void lnkDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
        LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;
        GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        string fileid = Convert.ToString(GridView1.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        string name, type;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con1))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select namesScan, contentType, DataSurat from SrtMasuk where NoSurat=@NoSurat";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoSurat", fileid);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    Response.ContentType = dr["contentType"].ToString();
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                                        "attachment;filename=\"" + dr["namesScan"] + "\"");
                    Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["DataSurat"]);
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

my connection strings

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=HABIBDEA;Initial Catalog=kopma;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=ilovedea1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="kopmaConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=HABIBDEA;Initial Catalog=kopma;User ID=sa;Password=ilovedea1"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="kopmaConnectionString2" connectionString="Data Source=HABIBDEA;Initial Catalog=kopma;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=ilovedea1"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

if i try to download, there like no event / nothing happened, please where the code is wrong?, i think no code is incorrect, but why nothing happened while i click download ?

Comment: I think you have to use a commandname and commandargument instead of onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your GridView the Property

```
 OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
```

Add to your CodeBehind

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
       {
           switch (e.CommandName)
           {
               case "Download":
                   string fileid = e.CommandArgument;
```

and change your LinkButton to

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("NoSurat") %>'
Text="Download" CommandName="Download"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: ok done but, i have new problem at     Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

Comment: i showed you how to get the fileid -   GridViewRow  is not required

Comment: so what should i do to get fileid while gridviewrow not required ?

Comment: pass it by using the `CommandArgument`-Property of your `LinkButton`

Comment: well, perfeclty done, thank's for your help @fubo :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use rowCommand in grid view...

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="table table-striped responsive" ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="NoSurat" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting"  onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" PageSize="5">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No Surat">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblIDs" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NoSurat")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NoSurat")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Perihal" HeaderText="Perihal" SortExpression="Perihal" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="AsalSurat" HeaderText="Asal Surat" SortExpression="AsalSurat" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="IsiSurat" HeaderText="Isi Surat" SortExpression="IsiSurat" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="tglsurat_terima" HeaderText="Tanggal Diterima" SortExpression="tglsurat_terima" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="tglsurat_kirim" HeaderText="Tanggal Dikirim" SortExpression="tglsurat_kirim" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="keterangan" HeaderText="Ket Surat" SortExpression="keterangan" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="namesScan" HeaderText="Nama File" SortExpression="namesScan" />                     
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="tglupload" HeaderText="Tanggal Upload Surat" SortExpression="tglupload" />

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions" ShowHeader="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" CssClass="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" OnClientClick="return confirm('Anda yakin untuk menghapus?'); "></asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download"   CommandName="Download" ></asp:LinkButton>  
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>


 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
   {
        if (e.CommandName == "Download")
        {
            con1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
        LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;
        GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        string fileid = Convert.ToString(GridView1.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        string name, type;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con1))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select namesScan, contentType, DataSurat from SrtMasuk where NoSurat=@NoSurat";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoSurat", fileid);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    Response.ContentType = dr["contentType"].ToString();
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                                        "attachment;filename=\"" + dr["namesScan"] + "\"");
                    Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["DataSurat"]);
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }  
</code>
```

Comment: ok done but, i have new problem at Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Source Error: GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;